# What is the simplest way to declare an array that has the same values as another array with one extra position?

Tags: java

Basically if I have an array

```
String[] animals = {"dog", "cat", "pig"}
```

and I want to make an array

```
String[] animals2 = {"dog", "cat", "pig", x}
```

where x is arbitrary

Edit:
I know that ArrayList would be preferable here, but it's for a homework assignment and it requires that I use arrays.

Edit again:
I know this isn't the simplest because I can't use ArrayList or Arrays but I figured out the solution:

```
String[] name2 = new String[name.length + 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < name.length; i++)
    {
        name2[i] = name[i];
    }
    for (int k = name2.length - 1; k >= pos; k--)
    {
        name2[k] = name2[k - 1];
    }
    name2[pos - 1] = canName;
```

I needed the help to write my insertion sort, which inserts at point pos. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Instead of posting your solution in the question, please clarify the requirements in your question and post your solution as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 7):

```
String[] animals2 = Arrays.copyOf(animals,animals.length +1);
```

So you could then say `animals2[animals2.length-1] = x;`  assuming `x` is a `String`

Comment: That is easier, wow, I might go back and edit some old code :)

Comment: *"This will truncate a null"* makes no sense.  A `null` is a `null` and cannot be truncated.  Besides there is no truncation going on here at all.  Please rephrase this to say what you really mean.

Comment: @JasonSperske it looks easier, but if you go deeper, `Arrays.copyOf` invokes the method in your answer. :D

Comment: Looking at the JavaDoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(T[], int)

It says "Returns: a copy of the original array, truncated or padded with nulls to obtain the specified length"

Comment: FYI, Arrays.copyOf was introduced in Java 6 so if you're stuck using Java 5 or earlier, you should use Jason Sperske's solution. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16576403/44737

Answer (score 2):

If you couldn't use `java.util.Arrays` then this would work:

```
String[] animals2 = new String[animals.length+1];
System.arraycopy(animals, 0, animals2, 0, animals.length);
```

Comment: To clarify, `Arrays.copyOf` was introduced in Java 6, so it is not available in Java 5 and earlier.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the list is going to be dynamic use [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

```
List animals = new ArrayList();
animals.put('Dog');
animals.put('Cat');
animals.put('Pig');
animals.put('Donkey');
```

Comment: The thing is, this is for a homework assignment, and it says I need to use array. I know ArrayList would be simpler, but I can't use it.

Comment: You won't learn as much as you could if you let others do your homework you know.

Comment: I know. This is just a small part of the assignment I'm being tripped up by.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make many arrays, it would proably be best to use an arraylist. [Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) the documentation. There are many functions within the class that can be used to create arrays and give parameters to.